# Keyof loses known properties when applied on a type intersected with Record<string, unknown> and leads to incorrect type used with Omit<T, K>

Tags: typescript

I ran into an issue, I don't know if it's an actual problem or a misunderstanding on my side.

Considering this piece of code

```
type Props = {
  foo: string
  bar: string
} & Record<string, unknown>
// Using Record<string, unknown> seems to be the recommended way of saying "any object"

// Looks fine, no errors: the known properties seems to be kept in the intersection
const obj: Props = { foo: '', bar: '' }
type KeysOfProps = keyof Props // Here this type is "string"
```

For me:

- if `keyof Props is string` then `Props` shouldn't allow `obj` to have `toto` and `tata` being strings
- if `{ foo: string; bar: string }` is assignable to `Props`, then `keyof Props` should still have the `foo` and `bar` known properties. (else `foo` and `bar` should be unknown in my understanding)

It seem incompatible, but I figured out that `keyof Props` is probably `'foo' | 'bar' | string` which is simplified to `string`.

But, this causes some problems in my case. For example:

```
// This is Record<string, unknown>, `bar` is lost in the process
type PropsWithoutFoo = Omit<Props, 'foo'>

// This I can explain by the fact that Omit is described this way:
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
// `keyof T` being `string and K being 'foo': Exclude<string, 'foo'> is string
// Pick<Props, string> is 'foo' | 'bar' | unknown which is unknown
// => Every keys of the intersection is lost
```

This happened in a code with generics where `Record<string, unknown>` is actually a default type that could be replaced by any type that extends it. The lost of my properties seems to boil down to this, that's why I need to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is working as intended in TypeScript here. It looks to me like your bullet points are both misunderstandings: the `keyof` type operator is *lossy* when applied to types containing string indexes.  As you noted, `'foo' | 'bar' | string` is indeed just `string`; this is true, since a value of type `Props` can have any `string`-valued key.  If you write `Pick<XXX, keyof XXX>`, where `XXX` has a string index signature, you will therefore lose the known keys:

```
type PropsMissingKnownKeys = Pick<Props, keyof Props>;
/* type PropsMissingKnownKeys = {
    [x: string]: unknown;
} */
```

Note that this is different from a *direct* [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) of the form `K in keyof XXX`; in *that* case, the compiler will treat `in keyof` specially and iterate over each known key as well as the indexer:

```
type HomomorphicProps = { [K in keyof Props]: Props[K] };
/* type HomomorphicProps = {
    [x: string]: unknown;
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
} */
```

This leads to a possible different version of `Omit` implemented using the support for [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) as introduced in TypeScript 4.1:

```
type AlternativeOmit<T, K extends PropertyKey> = {
    [P in keyof T as Exclude<P, K>]: T[P]
}
```

`AlternativeOmit<T, K>` is a direct mapped type that iterates over each property key `P` in `T`, and remaps each key to `never` or `P` depending on whether or not `P` is assignable to `K`.  If you use that instead of `Omit`, the desired type comes out:

```
type PropsWithoutFoo = AlternativeOmit<Props, "foo">;
/* type PropsWithoutFoo = {
    [x: string]: unknown;
    bar: string;
} */
```

Since `AlternativeOmit` and `Omit` have different behavior, there may well be edge cases where `Omit` behaves the way you want and `AlternativeOmit` does not.  So I wouldn't say that you should just replace all instances of `Omit` with `AlternativeOmit`, and I *certainly* wouldn't suggest that TypeScript's library change the definition of `Omit`, which would affect everyone else.  As mentioned in [a relevant GitHub issue comment (microsoft/TypeScript#31501)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31501#issuecomment-501534342):

> All possible definitions of `Omit` have certain trade-offs; we've chosen one we think is the best general fit and can't really change it at this point without inducing a large set of hard-to-pinpoint breaks.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwLACgoFQBmCCAXFMsHAJYB2A5noVAEYCGcFVtjeAvlABkUAEoQAxgjgATADw96DADRQArnQDWdBAHc6APjwB6Y1ACqyJWMnT5ixqo3a9hyhAgBbVMARtowAAW0HC2np4QdDIQMlC67CBQCESUCdYAROx0iQisAFaSwOl4JmYAMqSaqET0EKo6UBBwiHDIFEHQLvpQYIiQcMA0EKjIHt5Qvv5QmhBgwFD0E8ELdMBNoxKDCHR4UnRUSfkU8EioGJjEpBQA5NeqHFxQt1D8eKCQUADSECDIAPJEE4odDTH7JWB9VCmKAACSaAUCNB84GgSKg6QcDGKuDeKNhCE8BOkYEREiBZywUAA2p8VqCQODyQBdY6QmlMl4AbhMACoJniYUTCXASTQyZCQTh8IQqQAPbjUJQs9RaHT6bnSggkciURWMDUsB4K3gMDWCHnGEq4d7QckAWSRVkYnzVdG+vxBMDFmjk5NUMwZKXJBg1xj5NohpwdyCdDBdrndFKlLDlxqVFGcrrNUAtVojAEEADZrOB0diDABuED+nhowDkABVVLSILK1lFUECmqB3QZJcwZTA6QHwQ2oOxUABRWUSQtqaK+5sGZUNqkwJkCPN48kAdTrgQQamAADFSCCiyWy5Xq7X6370dr0iHefyPrv94eT2fzgOCKndSayqZq4BqEEaAFKNmFpAA)

Comment: Really detailed and helpful answer, thanks a lot!